# Write to ext4 filesystem hang while lazyinit in background

Tags: linux, ext4, sles

I am running SUSE 12 on a node that has 6TB disks attached with EXT4 filesystem initialized. Lazyinit in the background takes atleast 24 hrs to complete. Write performance to the disk is significantly bad and hung most of the time while Lazyinit is in process.

While hung, we noticed lazyinit process is in Uninterpretable sleep mode.

```
root     35163  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        D    01:04   0:00 [ext4lazyinit]
```

Any suggestions to overcome this situation? Any better approach to initialize 6 TB (or more) FS?
By disable Lazyinit, it may take 5 hrs to complete initialization. But this approach do not work in our env.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently it was a bug in the kernel. 
It was fixed in https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/drivers/scsi/storvsc_drv.c?id=e86fb5e8ab95f10ec5f2e9430119d5d35020c951